# Rails: Auto-fill reference on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, new-operator

I have a resource "Project" nested inside a resource "Group". On my show group page, I list all the projects the group has. I also have added a "New Project" link leading to

```
new_group_project_path(@group)
```

But in the following new project form, the user still needs to enter the id of the group, even though he just clicked the New Project link on a specific group's page. I tried doing

```
<%= f.text_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
```

But @group seems to be nil, even though I passed it in the link.

How can I auto-fill this field with the group_id, or even hide the whole thing from the user, since it's already predetermined and he shouldn't have to think about that?

Thanks,

MrB

[edit]

Here's more of my code to clarify:

```
  1 class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  2   def new
  3     @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  4     @project = @group.projects.build
  5     respond_with(@project)
  6   end
  7 
  8   def create
  9     @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
 10     @project = @group.projects.build(params[:projects])
 11   end
 12 end
```

And in the _form.html.erb

```
 26   <% if @group.nil? %>
 25     <div class="field">
 26       <%= f.label :group_id %><br />
 27       <%= f.text_field :group_id %>
 28     </div>
 29   <% end %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
  5   resources :groups do
  4     resources :projects
  5   end
  6 
  7   resources :projects
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested the controllers in your routes.rb then you should not need to do anything extra in the form. So if your routes.rb looks something like this:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :projects
end
```

which it looks like from your path_helper, then you will always have the group_id available from the routing. So when the user submits the form to your create action in ProjectsController, you could handle it something like this:

```
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@project = @group.projects.build(params[:project])
```

Edit:

If @group is nil in your form (I'm guessing it is called in the new action) then you have the either add the @group = Group.find(params[:group_id]) in your new action as well (which would go against the DRY principal of Rails) or do what Ryan suggested and add it in a before_filter which could look like this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_group

  ...

private
  def find_group
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  end
end
```

That will make the @group variable available in all actions in this controller. The declaration of private only makes sure that nothing outside the Controller can make the call to find_group.

Comment: Personally I would put the `@group` definition in a `before_filter` and have it called before every action in the `ProjectsController`

Comment: That's what I did. What I don't understand is, how do I access the @group in my _form.html.erb? @group is always nil in there.

Comment: I did the build thing in the create action, not the before_filter. (to clarify)

Comment: I refactored it according to your tip, but @group is still nil in my new-form. I've posted my (unrefactored, as I didn't see your edit before) code above. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, even when I do @group = "hello" in the new action, @group is still nil in the form! Sounds like my controller isn't being used or something. Any ideas?

Comment: That is probably because you are rendering a partial from your new.html.erb. If you really want to use a partial for this then yo must pass the variabels through <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :group => @group } %> and then it should be available as only group (not @group) in the partial template

Comment: I've come to a similar conclusion and just tested if @group existed in the new.html.erb, but even there it's nil.

Comment: What happens if you remove the respond_with line? Don't replace it, just remove it.

Comment: @group is still nil. In fact I've removed everything but @group = "hello", to test if it's being passed to the view.

Comment: Strange, what does the logs say? Is the correct action called at all?

Comment: Started GET "/groups/1/projects/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-27 11:21:40 +0200
  Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"group_id"=>"1"}
Rendered projects/_form.html.erb (48.5ms)
Rendered projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application (89.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 220ms (Views: 179.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Seems okay to me. But if you assign @group = "hello" in ProjectsController#new and you output <%= @group %> in projects/new.html.erb  it shows nothing?

Comment: Exactly. I even wrote <% if @group.nil? %> nil <% end %> to check. It says 'nil' on the page. ProjectController def new @group = "hello" end, right? I must be missing something here.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I'll make a new question for this.

Comment: I found the mistake. I was in the wrong file, there was a project controller left over, I am now using the projects controller with an S *rolleyes*